# How to name independent ranges using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I'm trying to name a number of cells with a string variable and then adding a number. For now i have this but it doesnt loop through the cells and it just names the last one on the loopp, the D978. I would appreciate your help!

```
Sub NameRange_Add()
Dim cell As Range
Dim RangeName As String
Dim CellName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


'Single Cell Reference (Worksheet Scope)

For j = 3 To 8
For i = 2 To 6
RangeName = "tag" & i
CellName = "D97" & j

  Set cell = Worksheets("TAG AD").Range(CellName)
  Worksheets("TAG AD").Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=cell

  Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this loop doesn't look good. First of all, why are you using two `For`-Loops ? One Loop should be working fine as you only use the variable `i` for your name and `j` for your cell-range. Why don't use one variable for both? Or do you want to have 6 different names referencing one cell? Also you run into an error because you have same name for different cells with your approach.

Comment: Also the name `"tag" & i` will mess up with the column "TAG" so "TAG3" is an existing cell and cannot be used as name (lower case doesn't change a thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work, as it does for me:

```
Sub NameRange_Add()
Dim RangeName As String
Dim Reference As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 6
    RangeName = "MyTag" & i
    Reference = "='TAG AD'!$D$97" & i
    Worksheets("TAG AD").Names.Add name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=Reference
Next i

End Sub
```

This will produce the following referenced names:
[image: Sample]

If you need more assistence please leave a comment.

EDIT: Please note that you need to provide a **valid** name for the range as `"tag" & i` is not valid. You can check this manually by trying to add one of the names by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Although  i had to add 2 $ sings to work. If i ran your code it gave the names to G1973, i do not know why.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that information. Without the `$`'s it would only work if your selected cell is **A1** when executing the macro. I'll add this edit to the answer.